# Are there any reserved words in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, ado.net

**Three questions about reserved words:**

1. Are there any reserved words in SQLite? If so, what are they?
2. If there are reserved words, is the correct syntax for using one of them as a column or table name still to surround it with brackets? E.g., `[User]` or `[Name]`?
3. Are there any implications with using words that are reserved in other flavors of SQL (e.g., SQLServer) but not reserved in SQLite when using ADO.NET to query a SQLite database?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

1. Yes, see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html for the list.
2. You can bracket them, but it isn't standard SQL. Also, see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Thx +1, I was looking for a page like that, but couldn't find it :)