# Column Named Order - Big Database, How Should I Go About This?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any reserved words in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791611/are-there-any-reserved-words-in-sqlite)

I have a big database (veekun's pokedex for those who know of it) and one table has a column named "order". It's for sorting purposes, and I'm trying to `ORDER BY` that column, but it is a problem since `ORDER` is, of course, a reserved word. The two options I see are

1. Rename this column (but I'd like to avoid modifying the database as much as possible)
2. Get around this somehow

So, in the case of 1, how would I go about renaming the column without messing up the database too much?
In the case of 2, I can't imagine what I could do, but maybe there's a trick I don't know of to get around this.

I'm using SQLite and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to surround keyword collisions in `backticks`

Comment: I tried it with regular quotes and it worked, but since there's less chance I'll be using backticks in my PHP strings, I'll try this instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some databases support `` ` `` as escape character, others use `[…]`.  Looking up SQLlite's, it supports brackets:

```
order by [Order]
```

should work.

Comment: I can't select two answers, but quotes worked for me. I'm going to try this as well, just to learn both ways. Thanks!