# SQLite syntax error code 1

Tags: android, sqlite

So I am coding the database for my first Android application, but things went wrong with this code here.

```
public class MySQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SWMdatabase";
private static final String TABLE_WALLET = "Wallet";
private static final String TABLE_TRANSACTION = "Transaction";

private static final String KEY_WALLET_ID = "_WalletId";
private static final String KEY_TRANS_ID = "_TransId";

private static final String KEY_CREATED_ON = "CreatedOn";
private static final String KEY_WALLET_NAME = "WalletName";

private static final String KEY_WALLET_SUM = "WalletSum";
private static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "Amount";

public MySQLHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Database onCreate and onUpgrade
// --------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_WALLET_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_WALLET + " ( "
            + KEY_WALLET_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + KEY_WALLET_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
            + KEY_WALLET_SUM + " REAL NOT NULL )";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_WALLET_TABLE);

    String CREATE_TRANSACTION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRANSACTION + " ( " 
            + KEY_TRANS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
            + KEY_AMOUNT + " REAL NOT NULL, " 
            + KEY_WALLET_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + KEY_CREATED_ON + " TEXT NOT NULL )";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TRANSACTION_TABLE);

}
```

It throws an SQLiteException syntax error 'near "Transaction", and I have no idea how and why. I have also double check the CREATE_TRANSACTION_TABLE countless time, but still can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use [reserved words](http://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) **Transaction** for table creation.

See this post also [Are there any reserved words in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791611/are-there-any-reserved-words-in-sqlite)