# Failure 1 (near "table": syntax error) on 0x39c298 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE table (

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse

I'm trying to execute an app using a database of 200 students, but I have no clue what seems to be the issue with the creation of the database. Please help. Plus, it would also be helpful if someone could tell me how do I initialize just two columns and let the rest stay null.

```
public class Work {

public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_REG = "reg";
public static final String KEY_QUIZ1 = "q1";
public static final String KEY_QUIZ2 = "q2";
public static final String KEY_QUIZ3 = "q3";
public static final String KEY_CAT1 = "c1";
public static final String KEY_CAT2 = "c2";
public static final String KEY_TEE = "t";

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_REG + " TEXT, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_QUIZ1 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_QUIZ2 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_QUIZ3 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_CAT1 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_CAT2 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_TEE + " TEXT);"

                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TBALE IF EXIISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
public Work(Context c){
    ourContext = c;

}

public Work open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}
public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String string, String string2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_REG, string);
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, string2);
/*      cv.put(KEY_QUIZ1, string3);
    cv.put(KEY_QUIZ2, string4);
    cv.put(KEY_QUIZ3, string5);
    cv.put(KEY_CAT1, string6);
    cv.put(KEY_CAT2, string7);
    cv.put(KEY_TEE, string8);*/
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}


}
```

Can somebody please help me find the error? I am quite new to SQL and a bit aloof of its ways.

This is the code I used to create 200 entries in an SQLDatabase

```
        case R.id.bres:
        int i;
        boolean did=true;
        try{
        Work e = new Work(this);
        e.open();
        for(i=0;i<200;i++)
        {
            e.createEntry(reg2[i],na[i],"0","0","0","0","0","0");
        }
        e.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            did=false;
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Failed");
            TextView tv= new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Error");
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }
        finally{
            did=true;
        }
```

This is the code I used to display the data based on the entry chosen

```
        Work z = new Work(this);
        z.open();
        String qu1 ="QUIZ 1\n" + z.getq1(j);
        String qu2 ="QUIZ 2\n" +z.getq2(j);
        String qu3 = "QUIZ 3\n"+z.getq3(j);
        String ca1 ="CAT 1\n"+ z.getc1(j);
        String ca2 ="CAT 2\n"+ z.getc2(j);
        String te ="TERM END\n"+ z.gette(j);
        z.close();
        a.setText(qu1);
        b.setText(qu2);
        c.setText(qu3);
        d.setText(ca1);
        e.setText(ca2);
        f.setText(te);
```

This is the SQL Database class Work

```
public class Work {

public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_REG = "reg";
public static final String KEY_QUIZ1 = "q1";
public static final String KEY_QUIZ2 = "q2";
public static final String KEY_QUIZ3 = "q3";
public static final String KEY_CAT1 = "c1";
public static final String KEY_CAT2 = "c2";
public static final String KEY_TEE = "t";

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "stable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_REG + " TEXT, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_QUIZ1 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_QUIZ2 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_QUIZ3 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_CAT1 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_CAT2 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_TEE + " TEXT);"

                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TBALE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
public Work(Context c){
    ourContext = c;

}

public Work open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}
public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String string, String string2, String string3, String string4, String string5, String string6, String string7, String string8) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_REG, string);
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, string2);
    cv.put(KEY_QUIZ1, string3);
    cv.put(KEY_QUIZ2, string4);
    cv.put(KEY_QUIZ3, string5);
    cv.put(KEY_CAT1, string6);
    cv.put(KEY_CAT2, string7);
    cv.put(KEY_TEE, string8);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public String getq1(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";
    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUIZ1);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j;i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return res;
}

public String getq2(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";

    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUIZ2);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j;i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return null;
}

public String getq3(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";

    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUIZ3);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j;i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return null;
}

public String getc1(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";

    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CAT1);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j;i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return null;
}

public String getc2(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";

    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CAT2);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j;i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return null;
}

public String gette(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";
    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEE);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j;i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `table` is a keyword

Comment: `table` is a reserved word: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: or use ` to escape keyword `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE \`" + DATABASE_TABLE + "\` ("`. but it not recommended. don't use any resoved word as table name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use [reserved words](http://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) **table** for table creation.

See this post also [Are there any reserved words in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791611/are-there-any-reserved-words-in-sqlite)

And also change

```
db.execSQL("DROP TBALE IF EXIISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
```

to

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks.Have another issue.

Comment: @VirenChugh which issue,update your question with issue.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer.

Comment: @VirenChugh delete it from answer and add in your question and post  the error you are getting.

Comment: Done. The issue is actually unknown. Should I post the entire code?